# Spring MVC converter precedence over Security Method

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, spring-security, controller

I have a problem with Spring MVC and Security.

With this endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("test/{order}")
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public String getOrder(@PathVariable Order order) {
    return "test";
}
```

that use Spring MVC Conversion (to resolve the param to the related entity) and Spring Security (to authenticate the user), there is a strange behavior: If not authenticated, the response include a status code of 404 because the conversion system has a higher priority over method security.

There is a way to set an higher priority to security filters?

Thanks

Comment: No there isn't. Security is applied to methods using AOP so will only be effective if the method gets called. To call the method first the conversion etc. needs to be done without it it won't work. The only way you can circumvent this is by not using `@PreAuthorize` but by writing security rules in your spring security configuration.